# SSIS 2005 data flow how to get a column from a query

Tags: ssis

Context: SSIS 2005.

In my case, in data flow, I need to get a column (pk) from a table (t1). The query looks like this:

```
    select pk from t1
    where para1 between c1 and c2
        and para2 = c3
```

para1 and para2 will be parameters from the rows of previous component. So I tried lookup, but it can only do simple mapping between two tables. Also tried OLEDB command, but it can't return column in output. Any idea?

Comment: Don't have 2005 installed so not sure if this option is available in 2005. But you can check to see if you can select partial cache and then edit the lookup query to the where clause that  you have mentioned.

Comment: yes, although not very strait forward. I tried at first but got some strange error info. Then I tried deleting the lookup and start from scratch and it finally works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use partial cache in lookup/general options to access the Advanced tab where you can set a query with parameters:

[image]

[image]

[image]